# How to export variable which includes * (asterisk) sign in it?

Tags: macos, cron, operating-system, environment-variables, system

I have a cron job environment variable which I wanna export.

```
    export CRON="30 * * * * *"
```

The problem is * (asterisk) brings all file name in that folder. Which end up with an error.
For a quick try and understand the issue do followings.

1. Open terminal (I am using Mac)
2. `export TEST="30 *"`
3. `echo $TEST`
4. Check the output

Here Output will not

> 30 *

It's

> 30 `and all your files in that folder.`

PS:- This environment variable is getting read by one application and needs to use this in some function. 
ex :-

```
cron.schedule(CRON, function(){// some code handling})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your export command is okay and does not cause the asterisks to be expanded. The problem is your `echo $TEST`. The rules for POSIX shells cause the expansion of `$TEST` to occur before glob expansion. So what you are doing is actually this:

```
echo 30 *
```

If you quote the expansion to inhibit the glob expansion you will see what you expect:

```
echo "$TEST"
```

Your question is a good example why the POSIX 1003 shell behavior is awful. And so many new, innovative, shells like fish and elvish don't implement that behavior.

Comment: Double-quoting variable references is (almost) always a good idea in Posix shells. [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Comment: @kurtis-rader I have updated the situation scenario as I can't use double quote in my case.

Comment: Insufficient information. Your revised question still does not explain why you can't quote the variable. If the "application" that uses the var is a shell script then it is the responsibility of that script to quote any variables it uses if it does not want the value to undergo glob (i.e., file name) expansion. And if it is a binary program (e.g., compiled from C source) then the expansion won't occur. In other words you haven't clearly described the problem.

Comment: @KurtisRader Thanks Actually that was my fault double quote did work for me.